# Node Labels cut off in ggraph and ggsave

Tags: r, ggplot2

When I plot a network plot with node labels using ggraph, the labels regularly get cut off.

```
library(igraph)
library(ggraph)

#generate a sample network 
tstGr <- erdos.renyi.game(6, 0.5, type=c("gnp", "gnm"), directed = TRUE, loops = FALSE)
#Assign labels to the nodes
V(tstGr)$name = c("LongName1", "LongName2", "LongName3", "LongName4", "LongName5", "LongName6")

#Plotting function
PfuncLite = function(Gr){
  p = ggraph(Gr, layout = "circle")+
    geom_edge_fan(color = "#971b2f", alpha = 0.5, arrow = arrow(ends = "last", length = unit(0.15, "inches")), start_cap = circle(6, 'mm'), end_cap = circle(6, 'mm')) + 
    geom_node_label(aes(label = V(Gr)$name), color = "#002f6c") + 
    theme_graph()+
    ggtitle("Interaction Network") 
  return(p)
}

PlotTstGr = PfuncLite(tstGr)
PlotTstGr
```

If I change the width of the plot in ggsave I can eventually get a wide enough plot to include the whole label.

```
ggsave("TestPlot1.jpg", plot = PlotTstGr)
ggsave("TestPlot2.jpg", plot = PlotTstGr, width = 15)
```

The output graph TestPlot2.jpg then is stretched.  Is there a way to prevent the node labels from being cut off?  I can't tell if the issue is in ggraph or ggplot2.

Answer (score 1):

I figured this out, in geom_node_label, you can use the option repel = T

```
PfuncLite = function(Gr){
  p = ggraph(Gr, layout = "circle")+
    geom_edge_fan(color = "#971b2f", alpha = 0.5, arrow = arrow(ends = "last", length = unit(0.15, "inches")), start_cap = circle(6, 'mm'), end_cap = circle(6, 'mm')) + 
    geom_node_label(aes(label = V(Gr)$name), color = "#002f6c", repel = T) + 
    theme_graph()+
    ggtitle("Interaction Network") 
  return(p)
}
```

This is a call to ggrepel, so you can use other options there. I found that point.padding = NA, box.padding = 0, force = 0.1 were useful to keep nodes in place, but just to avoid them running beyond the boundaries.